# Retrieve the value of a color type variable in Typst

Tags: typst

I am using Typst, and I am working on a very simple [Polylux](https://github.com/andreasKroepelin/polylux/tree/main) theme. Below my actual code (saved in a file named `sorbonne-slides.typ`)

```
#import "@preview/polylux:0.3.1": *

// Color definitions
#let sorbonne-blue = rgb("#1D2769")
#let sorbonne-red = rgb("#AC182E")
#let sorbonne-lightblue = rgb("#52B5E5")
#let sorbonne-yellow = rgb("#FFB700")
#let sorbonne-text = rgb("#263068")

// Primary background color
#let primary-color = state("faculty-color", none)

#let sorbonne-theme(
  aspect-ratio: "16-9", 
  fontsize: 3em,
  faculty: none,
  body) = {

  set page(
    paper: "presentation-" + aspect-ratio,
  )

  set text(font: "Fira Sans", size: fontsize, fill: sorbonne-text)
  
  // update primary color according to variable 'faculty'
  if faculty == "sante" {
    primary-color.update(sorbonne-red)
  } else if faculty == "sciences" {
    primary-color.update(sorbonne-lightblue)
  } else if faculty == "lettres" {
    primary-color.update(sorbonne-yellow)
  } else {
    primary-color.update(sorbonne-blue)
  }
  
  body
}

// title-slide 
#let title-slide(
  title: [], 
  subtitle: [],
  author: [], 
  date: [], 
  location: []
  ) = {

    // background of the title slide
    let background = context primary-color.get()
    set page (
      fill: background,
    )

    set text(
      fill: white, 
      size: 35pt
    )
  
    grid(
      columns: auto, 
      rows: (0.60fr, 0.40fr), 
      row-gutter: 1em,
      align(horizon)[
        #strong(title)
        #parbreak()
        #strong(text(size: .7em,  subtitle))
      ],
      align(top)[
        #text(size: .7em, author)
        #parbreak()
        #text(size: .7em, location)
        #parbreak()
        #text(size: .7em, date)
      ] 
    )    
  }
```

When I try to create a title slide using the following code:

```
#import "sorbonne-slides.typ": *

#show: sorbonne-theme.with(aspect-ratio: "16-9", faculty: "sante")

#title-slide(
  title: [A funny title], 
  subtitle: [A funny subtitle],
  author: [A funny author],
  date: [2024-03-18], 
  location: [A funny department], 
)
```

I have the following error:

```
error: expected color, gradient, pattern, or none, found content
   ┌─ \\?\C:\Users\3121805\Dropbox\programmes\polylux templates\sorbonne-slides-typst\sorbonne-slides.typ:45:12
   │
45 │       fill: background,
   │             ^^^^^^^^^^

help: error occurred in this call of function `title-slide`
```

I really don’t understand where this error could be coming from, and why the ‘background’ variable doesn’t ultimately contain the color I’m trying to assign to it based on the value of the ‘faculty’ parameter. Does anyone have an idea of what the issue might be here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why `context primary-color.get()` doesn't work

`context` will always return content:

```
#type(5) // "integer"

#type(context 5) // "content"
```

The trick is to perform all operations that *need* a context *inside* that context:

```
#let title-slide(..) = context {
//                     ^^^^^^^ This is the change
// ...

// Now that we're inside a context, this will work as expected
let background = primary-color.get()

// ...
}
```

With this change, the whole `title-slide` gets access to the context which lets you use states as expected.

## Why your code produces unexpected results

- https://github.com/typst/typst/issues/2987 explains that the lack of color change is an open bug.
- `set page` operations need to clear the current page when they are applied. When you `set` inside the context, a second `set` is needed to revert everything back outside the scope. So after the `context {...}`, the second `set` to turn the color normal results in the new page.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! When I put "context" before the whole {...} part, there is no more error during the typst compilation. But the resulting pdf file is strange. First, there are two slides (I was expecting just one). Second, the background of the two slides is white (I was expecting the color to change according to the "faculty" value). Sorry, I must be missing something else...

Comment: @eusebe I've updated the answer to explain why it doesn't work as you expect. Page coloring is apparently an ongoing typst issue. You can get around it by performing a manual `#pagebreak()` (or any content) before your title slide, but this of course will leave a blank white page at the start of your deck.

Comment: Oh thank you for your very clear explanations!